# Undefined reference with -static?

Tags: c++, freebsd, static-linking, undefined-reference, clang++

When I try to compile my program with `CFLAGS = -static` i receive an error undefined reference.

When compiling without static works perfectly.

My question is why the static error gives me undefined reference?
I installed with `pkg install mysql57-server`
And linked  `mysql_config --libs`

Help ?

Comment: It would help if you told us *what* errors you get. Then we can easier tell you what you're missing.

Comment: `CFLAGS` is used for compilation flag, and `-static` is a linker flag. But anyway, please give us more data on your problem, like what is your compiler error log exactly?

Comment: Welll  this is without static  http://prntscr.com/aale29   And this with static  http://prntscr.com/aalev7

Comment: Perhaps you need to install the static libs for mysql? Is it a separate package on your system?

Comment: Will this help, it says to install the client package as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542591/equivalent-to-libmysqldev-freebsd

Answer (score 1):

When linking static libs, the order in which they come in command line matters (well, at least on FreeBSD). Try putting `-lmysqlclient` before/after all libraries.

And make sure there is `/usr/local/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.a` too, of course.